# Showing a div when radio button selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button, dropdown

I am creating a list of radio button selections for an order form. Each of the questions has an answer that contains a div with additional information. I have them all set up to show the div when the radio button is clicked, but when you go to the next question and click an option, it hides the above answer and unselects the radio button for the previous question.

**Edit To Clarify: Only one of the radio button options should bring up the additional info box per question. So if you click yes to question 1, you get an info box. If you click NO on question 1, there is no info box.**

I would like the previous radio buttons to stay selected. I started with this code and modified it to have multiple questions:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>test</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  .hide{
    display:none;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="tabs">
    <div id="nav">
      <p>Show Div 1:<input type="radio" name="tab" value="pkfrom" class="div1" /></p>
      <p>Show Div 2:<input type="radio" name="tab" value="pkfrom" class="div2" /></p>
    </div>

    <div id="div1" class="tab">
      <p>this is div 1</p>
    </div>

    <div id="div2" class="tab">
      <p>this is div 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    (function(){
      var tabs =document.getElementById('tabs');
      var nav = tabs.getElementsByTagName('input');

      /*
      * Hide all tabs
      */
      function hideTabs(){
        var tab = tabs.getElementsByTagName('div');
        for(var i=0;i<=nav.length;i++){
          if(tab[i].className == 'tab'){
            tab[i].className = tab[i].className + ' hide';
          }
        }
      }

      /*
      * Show the clicked tab
      */
      function showTab(tab){
        document.getElementById(tab).className = 'tab'
      }

      hideTabs(); /* hide tabs on load */

      /*
      * Add click events
      */
      for(var i=0;i<nav.length;i++){
        nav[i].onclick = function(){
          hideTabs();
          showTab(this.className);
        }
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lenniejane/d58phaua/

Comment: Your radio buttons need to be grouped by name, calling them all "tab" will just put them all in the same group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to put different names of radio buttons, I also made some changes in html :

```
<div id="tabs">
  <div class="nav">
    <p><strong>QUESTION 1</strong></p>

    <div class="answers">
      <p><input name="tab" type="radio" value="residential-yes">Yes</p>
      <p><input name="tab" type="radio" value="residential-no">No</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tab" id="div1">
      <p class="fee-notice">ADDITIONAL INFO 1</p>
      <p>ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>


  <div class="nav">
    <p><strong>QUESTION 2</strong></p>


    <div class="answers">
      <p><input name="tab2" type="radio" value="lift-yes">Yes</p>
      <p><input name="tab2" type="radio" value="lift-no">No</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tab" id="div2">
      <p class="fee-notice">ADDITIONAL INFO 2</p>
      <p>ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>


  <div class="nav">
    <p><strong>QUESTION 3</strong></p>

    <div class="answers">
      <p><input name="tab3" type="radio" value="inside-yes">Yes</p>
      <p><input name="tab3" type="radio" value="inside-no">No</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tab" id="div3">
      <p class="fee-notice">ADDITIONAL INFO 3</p>
      <p>ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>


  <div class="nav">
    <p><strong>QUESTION 4</strong></p>

    <div class="answers">
      <p><input name="tab4" type="radio" value="inside-yes">Yes</p>
      <p><input name="tab4" type="radio" value="inside-no">No</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tab" id="div4">
      <p class="fee-notice">ADDITIONAL INFO 4</p>
      <p>ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</p>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

css :

```
.tab {
  display: none;
}

.nav.showtab .tab{
  display:block;
}
```

and js will be like this :

```
var inputsEle = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var navEle = document.getElementsByClassName('nav');

for(i=0; i<inputsEle.length; i++){
    inputsEle[i].addEventListener("change", function(e){
        var thiisNav = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
        diplayNewTab(thiisNav)
    });
}

function diplayNewTab(thiisNav){
    for(i=0; i<navEle.length; i++){
            navEle[i].classList.remove("showtab");
    }
    thiisNav.className += ' showtab';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d58phaua/2/

**UPDATE:**

if you need to keep the "additional info" for previous questions visible when answering another question use this js :

```
var inputsEle = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var navEle = document.getElementsByClassName('nav');

for(i=0; i<inputsEle.length; i++){
    inputsEle[i].addEventListener("change", function(e){
        var thiisNav = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
        thiisNav.className += ' showtab';
    });
}
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/d58phaua/3/

Comment: How would I keep the "additional info" for previous questions visible when the next question is answered? It's still collapsing that div when I click an answer on the next question.

Comment: Sorry, that's still not doing what I need it to. The additional info box should only show up when a certain radio button is clicked. So if they click Yes on the first question, they get an additional info box. If they click no on the first question, there is no additional info box. This shows the additional info no matter what button is clicked.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d58phaua/4/ in this fiddle the additional info showing only if the user choose yes, I hope this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/d58phaua/1/

Here you go.

You just need to put different names of radio buttons

```
<input name="tab1" type="radio" value="residential-no">No</p>
```